# Expand/collapse right menu in pure html/css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achive below effect
[image]

But I have the problem with input label - if I will create two divs, the checkbox effect is not working. And also have the problem with css grid to reverse that column.

Working on:

- before click we see only white column,
- after the click we see yellow column,
- we can switch it via clicking

Stackblitz with current version:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-vgaaxb

```js
const appDiv = document.getElementById('app');
appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>JS Starter</h1>`;
```

```css
h1,
h2 {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.filter-menu {
  border-radius: 0px 8px 8px 0px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #71bccd;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgba(55, 58, 60, 0.2);
  font-size: 14px;
  min-width: 62px;
}

.filter-content {
  width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input#menu {
  display: none;
}

label {
  padding-top: 10vh;
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
}

.filter-menu label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked~.filter-content {
  width: 425px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>

<div class="filter-menu">
  <input type="checkbox" id="menu">
  <label for="menu">CLICK TO EXPAND</label>
  <div class="filter-content" style="background-color: #ffd813">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code. External links are permitted, but only when they are used along side the code in the question itself. See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also, it is not possible to achieve something like this in pure HTML & CSS, you must already be using JS. If you want to continue to use JS then please rephrase your question to make it clear.

Comment: @FluffyKitten It is definitely possible using a trick with checkboxes and my answer is proof :)

Comment: Without going to the external website, it was impossible to understand the OP was trying to achieve based on the question alone, and that is against Stack Overflow guidelines - external links can break or change over time and make the question invalid or unclear. @profiler, even though you have an answer, please update the question so that it meets the guidelines and might be useful to other users with similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following to achieve your desired effect:

```css
.filter-menu {
  ...
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

This will arrange the elements in inverse order, placing the yellow first (left)

```css
input:checked~.filter-content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

This will make the yellow div fill the rest of the space when visible

```
label {
  ...
  padding-right: 100px;
}
```

I also gave the label a right padding to place it more in the middle, like in the picture. You can adjust this `100px` to whatever suits your needs. **Note** that you can click in this whitespace to toggle the menu. If you do not want this, use `margin-right: 100px;` instead.

```js
// Import stylesheets
//import './style.css';

// Write Javascript code!
const appDiv = document.getElementById('app');
appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>JS Starter</h1>`;
```

```css
h1,
h2 {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.filter-menu {
  border-radius: 0px 8px 8px 0px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #71bccd;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgba(55, 58, 60, 0.2);
  font-size: 14px;
  min-width: 62px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.filter-content {
  width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input#menu {
  display: none;
}

label {
  padding-top: 10vh;
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  padding-right: 100px;
}

.filter-menu label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked~.filter-content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>

<div class="filter-menu">
  <input type="checkbox" id="menu">
  <label for="menu">CLICK TO EXPAND</label>
  <div class="filter-content" style="background-color: #ffd813">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! there is possibility that before click for yellow side, the white side is thinner? Like ~60px?

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, you can edit the `100px` padding on the label to `60px` or any value you want.

Comment: Thank you, is the perfect solution. I will try also use z-index:999 on yellow page. But.. hmmm... not working.

Comment: That seems like an unrelated issue. If you cannot fix it, you should probably ask it in a new question